# How to define a function locally in lisp?

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

I need to define a function inside a let and be able to immediately use it, like this:

```
(let ((test (lambda () (print "ha")))) 
    (test))
```

However, since test is a variable (and not a function), it doesn't work. Instead I need to run it like this:

```
(let ((test (lambda () (print "ha")))) 
    (funcall test))
```

In my case this is a problem. I could solve this by making a macro that changes (test) to (funcall test), however, this would not work, since the macro's name would be the same as the method in my case (I'm guessing this would cause (test) to become (funcall test) => (funcall (funcall test)) => ...?)

Is there any way to define a method in a lambda and run it immediately, without something like funcall?

Comment: functions are called *functions*, not *methods*. There are no *local methods*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Special Operator FLET, LABELS, MACROLET](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_flet_.htm)
. Note the difference between `FLET` and `LABELS`. In particular, `LABELS` can define (mutually) recursive functions, whereas `FLET` can shadow an existing function while being able to call that function itself:

```
(defun foo () (flet ((foo () (foo))) (foo)))
       ^1             ^2      ^1      ^2

(defun foo () (labels ((foo () (foo))) (foo)))
       ^1               ^2      ^2      ^2
```

Answer (score 6):

> I could solve this by making a macro that changes (test) to (funcall test), however, this would not work

Why not?

```
CL-USER 4 > (let ((test (lambda () (print "ha"))))
              (macrolet ((test ()
                           `(funcall test)))
                (test)))

"ha" 
"ha"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `labels` for this, in the same way you use `let` for variables. ie:

```
(labels ((test ()
             (print "ha")))
    (test))
```